# How to set the icon of a c++ console application from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Previously I used to use Visual Studio 2019 for building my software and setting an icon in Visual Studio is easy. But due to some problem, we shifted to Visual Studio Code and Cmake to build my project. But now I cannot set the application icon. Please help.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++17?

Comment: Visual Studio just modified a resource file, just do that yourself

Comment: In Visual studio I edited the resource file. But in Visual studio code I do not have a resource file.